# Serialize POJO to JSON through a provider

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, osgi

What is a common way to serialize Java Beans to JSON in a automatic fashion? The `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` doesnt seem to handle the conversion under the hood. Do we create our own JSON Providers or is there another way? Currently im trying to handle it via the ContextResolver:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html

It is my understanding that the `@Produces` annotation should help create the expected output if a java object is returned from one of the resource class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to code the jackson based provider yourself.

In apache karaf you can simply install the feature **aries-jax-rs-whiteboard-jackson**.
If you are not using karaf you can install the bundles from the feature yourself:

https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/master/jax-rs.features/src/main/feature/feature.xml

Comment: I compiled the dependency using gradle now.